# A question on a subspace of $C[0,1]$, that is closed in $L^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S$ be a subspace of $C[0,1]$, that is closed  as a subspace of $L^{2}[0,1]$.

a. Show that $S$ is closed  in $(C[0,1], ||.||_{\infty})$.

b. Show that there  is a constant $M$ such that for all $f\in S$, we have $||f||_{\infty} < M||f||_{2}$.

c. Show that for each $y\in [0,1]$, there is a function $k_{y}$ in $L^{2}$, such that for all $f\in S$ we have $f(y)=\int k_{y}(x)f(x) dx$.

My attempt: I have solved the first two questions. The first question follows from the fact that $||f||_{2}\leq ||f||_{\infty}$.

Then part (b) is just the bounded inverse theorem.

I am stuck at (c). I thought to define a map say $\phi: L^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $\phi(f)=f(y)$ , for a fixed $y\in [0,1]$. If $\phi$ is continuous then by Riesz's representation theorem there exists a $k_{y} \in L^{2}$ such that $$\phi(f)= \int k_{y}(x)f(x)dx = f(y)$$, and we are done. The second inequality can help in showing the continuity but only for $f\in S$. Is this map at all bounded? How can this be solved.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you have solved part b, part c can be solved, as you suggest, using the Riesz representation theorem.  For $y\in[0,1]$ define $\phi:S\to\mathbb C$ by $\phi(f)=f(y)$ for $f\in S$. Then for $f\in S$ we have 
$$|f(y)|\leq\|f\|_\infty\leq M\|f\|_{L^2}$$
Thus the linear functional $f\mapsto f(y)$ is $L^2$ bounded, hence the Riesz representation theorem can be applied, so there is some $k_y\in S$ such that $\phi(f)=\langle f, k_y\rangle$.

Comment: But the inequality in (2) holds for $f\in S$. Then how can the evaluation map be bounded?

Comment: So the evaluation map we are concerned with are you saying that map is tha dual space of $L^{2}$.

Comment: What is $M$ here?

Comment: Sorry, $M$ is obtained for part b of the problem.

Comment: Why $\phi$ is a map from $M \to \mathbb{C}$?  $M$ is just some constant!

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to using $M$ to denote a subspace. I think everything is cleared up now.

Comment: But $\phi \in S^{*}$. How can we use Riesz Representation theorem now? $\phi$ is not in the dual of $L^{2}$

Comment: $S$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space, hence is itself a Hilbert space.

Comment: Yeah that;s correct I get it now.. So actually this $k_{y}$ is continuos right ?Actually $k_{y} \in S$. So it is stronger than saying $k_{y}\in L^{2}$.

Comment: Yep $k_y\in S$.